# Check for the event type of a listener

Tags: actionscript-3, listener, addeventlistener

I would like to check the event type of a listener.
This gives me an error:

```
messagefield.addEventListener(SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE,  newLayout);

function newLayout(event:Event=null) {
if(event.type == SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE){
trace("OK")
}
}
```

How to do check for it?

Comment: Please say or copy the error message you get. Is it a null object reference from your default parameter? Do you really need that?

Comment: Yes, it's a "null object reference" error.

Comment: As stated in Pan-s answer, the idea behind your code is OK, your problem occured while trying to access the type of a null object (hence the null object reference error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your newLayout function can accept null parameter, You should check if event is null before use it

```
function newLayout(event:Event=null) {

   if (event && event.type == SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE) {
         trace("OK")
   }

}
```